# T-SQL query for conditional string cocatenation

Tags: sql, sql-server, string-concatenation

| PersonID | Name | ResultDate | CategoryName | CategoryValue |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 569 | A | 2015-11-10 | Note | NULL |
| 569 | A | 2015-11-10 | Result | Passed |
| 569 | A | 2015-11-10 | Score | 16 |
| 585 | B | 2015-11-09 | Note | Hello! |
| 585 | B | 2015-11-09 | Result | Failed |
| 585 | B | 2015-11-09 | Score | 8 |
| 585 | B | 2020-03-01 | Note | NULL |
| 585 | B | 2020-03-01 | Result | Passed |
| 585 | B | 2020-03-01 | Score | 10 |

I have this table of exam results in SQL Server.

Each `PersonID` can have multiple `ResultDate` rows, and for each `ResultDate` they always have `CategoryName` values of `Note`, `Result`, and `Score`.

I want to concatenate the `CategoryValues` columns whose `CategoryName` are `Result` and `Score`, so I have a `Result(Score)` format.

For example, for PersonID 569 on 2015-11-10 I want to see `Passed(16)`.  For PersonID 585 I want to see 'Failed(8)' for 2015-11-09 and `Passed(10)` for 2020-03-01.

How can I achieve this?

I've tried STRING_AGG and CONCAT with conditional queries but failed.

Comment: Your desired result is not clear. "For PersonID 585, I want to see 'Failed(8)' for 2015-11-09, and 'Passed(10)' for 2020-03-01." - is this supposed to be a single string, or two separate records returned? Is the date supposed to be part of the result?

Comment: Why aren't you storing your data in a more normalised view? Though this looks like an EAV design, so doing the concatenation to "Englishfy" the values would therefore be better done in your application.

Comment: Instead of describing your desired results please include it as tabular data eg are you after an additional column for your sample data? Something else?

Comment: "I've tried STRING_AGG and CONCAT ..."  Where???  We do not see your try in the query.  How can we help you if you don't post your query???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use STRING_AGG with CONCAT, it's somewhat unpretty though:

```sql
select personid,name, ResultDate
, string_agg(CONCAT(CategoryValue, case when CategoryName = 'Result' THEN ' (' ELSE ')' END), '') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY case when CategoryName = 'Result' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) AS Result
from (
    VALUES  (569, N'A', N'2015-11-10', N'Note', NULL)
    ,   (569, N'A', N'2015-11-10', N'Result', N'Passed')
    ,   (569, N'A', N'2015-11-10', N'Score', N'16')
    ,   (585, N'B', N'2015-11-09', N'Note', N'Hello!')
    ,   (585, N'B', N'2015-11-09', N'Result', N'Failed')
    ,   (585, N'B', N'2015-11-09', N'Score', N'8')
    ,   (585, N'B', N'2020-03-01', N'Note', NULL)
    ,   (585, N'B', N'2020-03-01', N'Result', N'Passed')
    ,   (585, N'B', N'2020-03-01', N'Score', N'10')
) t (PersonID,Name,ResultDate,CategoryName,CategoryValue)
WHERE CategoryName IN ('Result', 'Score')
group by personid, name, resultDate
```

Outputs:

| personid | name | ResultDate | Result |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 569 | A | 2015-11-10 | Passed (16) |
| 585 | B | 2015-11-09 | Failed (8) |
| 585 | B | 2020-03-01 | Passed (10) |

Comment: This fixed the issues for what I've tried with STRING_AGG and CONCAT. Couldn't think about this way. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this. This is simple, but clear, for my mind =)

```
with r as (
  select distinct PersonID, Name, ResultDate
  from mytable
)
select   r.*
         , concat((select CategoryValue from mytable where personId=r.PersonId and resultDate=r.resultDate and CategoryName='Result')
          , ' (', (select CategoryValue from mytable where personId=r.PersonId and resultDate=r.resultDate and CategoryName='Score'), ')') result
from     r
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/h-hfU2Z2

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT r0.PersonID, r0.Name, r0.ResultDate
   , MIN(r0.CategoryValue) + '(' + MIN(r1.CategoryValue) + ')' As Result
FROM ExamResults r0
INNER JOIN ExamResults r1 ON r1.PersonID = r0.PersonID AND r1.ResultDate = r0.ResultDate
   AND r1.CategoryName = 'Score'
WHERE r0.CategoryName = 'Result'
GROUP BY r0.PersonID, r0.Name, r0.ResultDate
```

See it work here:

> https://dbfiddle.uk/AEWDZq1k

Answer (score 0):

Try this eg using String_agg

```
SELECT STRING_AGG(ConcatenatedValues, ' and  ') AS result
FROM (
    SELECT
        PersonID,
        concat( STRING_AGG(CategoryValue, ', '), ' for ',ResultDate) AS 
        ConcatenatedValues
    FROM ExamResult
WHERE CategoryName IN ('Result', 'Score') AND PersonID = 585
GROUP BY PersonID, ResultDate) a
```